# Rails 3 page keywords & description

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model `Page` with additional fields `keywords` and `description` for SEO.

How to implement the SEO functionality in Rails and add `meta` tags with keywords and description on every page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to have a look at two plugins:

https://github.com/mokolabs/headliner
https://github.com/lassebunk/metamagic

And read about other SEO techniques for Rails applications here:

http://lassebunk.dk/2011/03/09/rails-seo-pack/

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are storing separate keywords and description for each page in your Page model.

You make a layout that is available for all your pages, that shows instance variables (formatted the way you want them) @keywords and @description.